Are probabilities in games of chance any more objective than in other contexts?
As a disclaimer, by “objective”, I do not mean “objective” in the sense of everyone agreeing upon a certain matter. By objective, I mean a certain notion of a probability that does not depend on the mind at all.
Now, in games of chance, we often have defined probabilities for these games. The probability of a coin landing on heads is 1/2. The probability of a dice landing on 4 is 1/6. And the probability of drawing a card from a deck of 52 is 1/52.
On the other hand, we often talk about probabilities in contexts of events that are unrelated to games of chance, or even events that don’t seem repeatable. For example, you could ask the question: “How probable is it that John is the murderer of this body?”
Are the probabilities of the latter type any more objective than the former?

Note: perhaps another word to use would be ontological. In other words, is there a difference in the ontological status of probabilities between these different topics?

Does arithmetic exist without the mind at all? Don't we need minds to pick out  one thing over there and one thing over here and associate them together as representing "two"

The crucial difference is in the easy "listability" of possibilities (a "sample space").
If you roll a die, there are six and only six possible outcomes, easily distinguished from each other, and everybody can quickly list them.
If you find a body, there are ... how many possible scenarios? What exactly are they? By what are they distinguished? Can you list them?

@TorstenSchoeneberg Agreed. But the difference in listabilities of possibilities seems epistemic, not “objective”.

@Annika I don’t think one has to be a platonist to still ascribe a mind independent meaning to the statement “there are two apples in front of me.” I’m not sure though, but either way, I don’t think this is directly relevant to what’s being asked

Interestingly, you could draw a lot of parallels between the dice and the murderer.  Only one person could actually be the murderer, the probabilities only reflect a lack of information.  For a dice roll, it's only "random" if you lack knowledge of exactly how its thrown.  For a deck of cards, it's only random if you dont know how the deck has been shuffled.  The randomness reflects missing information.

I'm with @PaulRoss The question of the various degrees of probability is one of the main focuses of an entire SEP article called Interpretations of Probability that addresses objective and subjective measure of probability.

I think the notion of objective probability you are taking here is "non-epistemic" - the probability of some event X can be defined without reference to an observer or mind's state of knowledge.
A good example here is the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution of molecular velocities in a gas. It is defined as...

The fraction of the particles within an infinitesimal element of the three-dimensional velocity space d3v, centered on a velocity vector
v of magnitude v for a system containing a large number of identical non-interacting, non-relativistic classical particles in thermodynamic equilibrium.

The velocity of any individual particle is random and will change extremely often at atmospheric gas densities (i.e., assuming its not a rarefied gas). However, if you opened a (very very small) valve and wait for a single particle p to come out, the probability that the velocity of the particle, v(p) will fall in some range dv will be objectively given by the maxwell-boltzmann distribution -- in facet, once you record teh velocities of all the particles coming out it will basically match the distribution (i.e., your sample distribution will converge to the maxwell-boltzmann distribution).
There is nothing in here about an observer's beliefs, knowledge, etc. We are describing it from nowhere basically.
In that sense, any physically-generated process can be described by objective probability. Rolling a die can be seen as one example, although it's less pure here because a person is rolling it. But the distribution of wave heights in a small patch of ocean, the distribution of molecular orientations in an amorphous crystalline solid, etc are all things that have a meaningful probability that must describe one, actual world.
You may say "Well those are descriptive statistics/distributions being layered on top of a deductively true state of affairs" and thus sneaking in subjective probability via our choice of sampling process. However, we don't need a random process to guarantee valid sample statistics. There are ways to define a sampling process that take into account the natural symmetries of the thing being sampled, so we don't accidently, say, sample a wave at a frequency equal to its periodicity, only choose rich people for our sample, etc.
The more general idea is that any ergodic process can be described objectively by probability and as long as your sampling algorithm doesn't (a) adapt or change based on sample results (i.e., "peek before sample") and (b) is relatively prime with respect to the various symmetries relevant to the dimensions over which you are sampling (e.g., the sampling interval of a wave is relatively prime to the period of the wave).
So the above seems to satisfy the objectivity part of probability (at least relative to physical chance processes like rolling dice), so yes, the example you posted can be seen as a description of physical chance vs epistemological uncertianty.

I think what you’re highlighting is that certain things occur in constant frequencies and others don’t. I don’t think this is the same as certain things occurring under constant probabilities and others don’t. There is technically nothing preventing you from assigning a counterintuitive 1/3 probability to a dice rolling on 6, even if historical frequencies of 6 on that particular dice were about 1/6 of all dice rolls. A 1/3 probability may be more intuitively assigned if one already knows that the dice didn’t land on 3 or 4 or 5 either. And yet, this wouldn’t match the historical frequency.

@Syed the propensity interpretation of probability would  say they are

the interpretation says that, yes, but I don’t think there’s any way to possibly demonstrate that. How would you demonstrate that a dice has a certain “inkling” towards landing on each roll? What would be the physical manifestation of this? Probabilities are ultimately always tested against frequencies anyways, including in quantum mechanics, and we all agree that frequencies are objective. @Annika

@Syed "we all agree that frequencies are objective" - doesn't that answer your question? If a coin has a propensity to land heads 1/2 of the time, we'd see it reflected in the resulting probabilities. Or, in the case of a gas, each molecule has a propensity to achieve a particular velocity at any given time.

a coin could land on heads 1/2 of the time if there is a purely deterministic process as well, and well, it pretty much is modelled as that anyways. But if it’s deterministic, each coin technically is determined to land on only one face of the coin. So in what sense does it have a physical/mind independent propensity to land on both faces? @Annika

@Syed you've asked about probability a lot on this site and as someone who has degrees and 20+ years of experience in probability (and reading philosophy of probability) I'm not really sure what you are trying to get at with your programme of questions. We have examples of physical probabilities, which are observable via frequency as you've stated. I'm not sure what else you'd need to verify probability can be objective (it isn't always).

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

read my last comment. I also have experience in probability although am much younger and what makes probability “objective” is a far murkier picture than you think. See constructor theory

@Syed -- yes, this is what I was getting at that in a deterministic world all probability is epistemic

@Syed and Annika: relevant.

No. First of all, objectivity is a man-made concept(*).
Assigning probabilities to events/outcomes, is our way of expressing lack of information or knowledge regarding how a process unfolds in time. By saying that rolling the dice has a chance of 1/6 for a specific outcome is like saying that if someone will be murdered there is equal chance that everybody else could be the murderer. By investigating the murder, we could find the murderer, as by watching in a video how the dice rolled we could understand the specific outcome of the rolling.

(*) Whether we like it or not, objectivity is an illusion, not per se, but as a certainty (from out part): it exsists only in our minds. Scientists like objectivity, but they find it only in coarse grained experiments. When they dive into the phenomena, the only way to express them is in terms of probabilities ...

Agreed with the main part of your answer but the addendum at the bottom seems nothing more than an opinion. How do you know that probability is inherent in things?

@Sye, I no not clain that probability is inherent in things, what I do clain though, is that what-is-inherent-in-things is beyond our reach, so we can only "frame" it with probabilities.

You ask: Are probabilities in games of chance any more objective than in other contexts? And you qualify 'objective' to mean mind-independent, rather than merely intersubjectively agreed upon.
To answer this question specifically, I would say a definite no. Games of chance are paradigm cases of epistemic or subjective probability.
Suppose Alice is playing poker against Bob and she must decide whether to call or fold. She has to assess the probability that her hand is stronger than Bob's because she cannot see Bob's hole cards. We the audience can see both sets of hole cards so we know who has the stronger hand. Alice's probability arises because she has incomplete information.
Similarly with a dice game such as backgammon. A player makes the best play they can based on an assessment of probabilities. The reason they must rely on probabilities is that they don't know what future rolls of the dice will bring.
The only mind-independent probabilities are the chancy physical probabilities of quantum mechanics and even then not according to all interpretations of QM. With the exception of those, probabilities represent our best efforts to handle incomplete information.

How is it objective in the case of QM, even in interpretations that are not deterministic? Even if we couldn’t in principle know whether a certain quantum event will result in one of many outcomes, one and only one outcome occurs. Other possible outcomes are merely imagined, just like in dice or poker games, so why is this not also epistemic?

In QM, other outcomes are not merely imagined, they might have actually happened, even given all the same circumstances. We can repeat an experiment with an identical setup and get a different result. We can describe the possible outcomes only with probabilities. In the epistemic case, if we had perfect information we could say exactly what will happen without the need for probabilities. In QM, the probabilities are fundamental. There are no (local) hidden variables such that if only we knew them we would know for certain what will happen.

they would have happened only under the many worlds interpretation. Repeating an experiment with an identical setup does not imply that all initial conditions were exactly the same. We can also repeat a dice experiment with an “identical” setup: multiple outcomes does not mean anything else was possible. Even if there were no local hidden variables, or even non local hidden variables, how does this imply that anything else could have happened?

In quantum experiments we can set up identical conditions - absolutely identical in every respect - and get different results. We cannot do that in a classical deterministic environment. If you roll dice twice and get different results, it's because something was different. A slightly different position or momentum or distance or surface or something. In the classical case we use probabilities only because we are lacking information. In the quantum case there is no information lacking - the information does not exist.

but the question is how do you know that the conditions are exactly identical, especially for the scale of quantum events where every little part of the conditions presumably makes a difference in measurement? If you can’t know this, the conclusion seems unwarranted. And even in quantum mechanics, non local hidden variables are not ruled out (and Bell’s experiments show that some form of non locality probably has to be accepted either way, unless you are an anti realist)

Non-local hidden variables are not ruled out, but we have no evidence they exist, and if they did they would be very weird and would violate special relativity. Non-locality is a separate issue. The point about quantum mechanics is that it is non-deterministic, unless perhaps you are willing to introduce talk of multiverses. Identical experiments can have different results and there is nothing beyond the wave function. There is no information that if only we knew it would render our theories deterministic.

non local hidden variables would imply determinism, so you don’t necessarily need multiple worlds. You’re ultimately just asserting an interpretation. P.S. The “Copenhagen” interpretation is instrumentalist anyways and doesn’t actually tell you about what’s going on. I would argue that’s weirder since it ultimately posits unexplained correlations in quantum entanglement. The “explanation” is the mathematical equations but equations are math. There is no complete ontology in this interpretation

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Games of chance are created by minds, so no they are not mind independent. The intended probability's involved and how we derive them in the "game" are systems created by minds.
Creating a cube with six numbers on it to model a 1/6 probability is only "objective" in the sense that this does do a reasonably good job at creating a system to model that particular intended probability.
When modeling other probability's that aren't made up by minds you get the messiness associated with trying to sus out how likely events are to actually occur, so we tend to relate real world probability's with the games we make up to model things for fun.
But no when I am modeling real life, roll playing like D&D setting up models like how many hit points a dagger does at what rate are created by human minds as a short cut to having a fairly simplified reality, it's really nothing like the world objectively is. If instead I was trying to model how likely it is to rain tomorrow in south eastern Pennsylvania it's much more difficult and messy requiring the collection of massive amounts of data and trying to extract from it real probability math for things that aren't depending on cubes to model things.

It depends on how you want to interpret the function of probability. In John Maynard Keynes's book A Treatise on Probability (1921) he argues against the Bayesian account by emphasizing that there is a "belief" justifying the basis on evidence. That means that one must take into account the reasoning and context involved in making the probabilistic determination. Keynes, therefore, provides a subjective account of probability that depends heavily on the individual's interpretation in the context, according to the logic of the situation. Keynes focuses more on the "logic of belief" rather than calculation in the Bayesian sense. Bayesian probability still incorporates subjective priors, but its ultimate focus and aim is to give an objective account of the data, by updating the calculation with new evidence. Hence, Bayesian probability is more of a quantitative method for updating one's beliefs in the face of new evidence.
Alfred North Whitehead's Process and Reality (1929) adopts Keynes's view of probability by writing:

This natural method of sampling is provided by the data which form the primary phase of any one actual occasion. Each actual occasion objectifies the other actual occasions in its environment. This environment can be limited to the relevant portion of the cosmic epoch. It is a finite region of the extensive continuum, so far as adequate importance is concerned in respect to individual differences among actual occasions. Also, in respect to the importance of individual differences, we may assume that there is a lower limit to the extension of each relevant occasion within this region. With these two presumptions, it follows that the relevant objectifications, forming the relevant data for any one occasion, refer to a finite sample of actual occasions in the environment. Accordingly our knowledge of the external world, and of the conditions upon which its laws depend, is, through and through, of that numerical character which a statistical theory of probability requires. Such a theory does not require that exact statistical calculations be† made. All that is meant by such a theory is that our probability judgments are ultimately derivable from vague estimates of ‘more or less’ in a numerical sense. We have an unprecise intuition of the statistical basis of the sort of way in which things happen.
NOTE.—By far the best discussion of the philosophical theory of
probability is to be found in Mr. J. Maynard Keynes’ book, A Treatise
on Probability. This treatise must long remain the standard work on
the subject. My conclusions in this chapter do not seem to me to
differ fundamentally from those of Mr. Keynes as set out towards the
conclusion of his Chapter XXI. But Mr. Keynes here seems to revert to
a view of probability very analogous to that form of the ‘frequency
theory’ which, as suggested by me, he criticized acutely (and
rightly, so far as concerned that special form) in his Chapter VIII.
(PR, 206)


The most significant difference between games of chance and other situations we describe with probabilities is not objectivity, but complexity. As a result, we feel more confident when we express these probabilities.
Coins, dice, and card decks are very simple. If these are constructed fairly, we can be very confident of the probabilities that you described.
We also use probabilities to describe weather predictions. Weather is a very complex process, with some chaotic aspects. With our current technology, we can only estimate approximate probabilities.
Another issue that comes up in many contexts is that we may not have all the necessary input data. This often applies to situations like your example of the probability that John is the murderer. Contrast this with rolling a die: the only thing we need to know is how many sides it has and whether it's a fair die -- the physics is relatively simple.
When we don't have all the necessary facts, we often substitute guesses and assumptions, which may be subjective. In this respect, games of chance could be considered more objective.

For your examples, for example the “four” on dice: There are six possible outcomes. There is no reason why any of the six outcomes would be more or less likely than any other. Since the sum of probabilities is 1 by definition, we assume that each outcome has probability one sixth.
We could examine the dice carefully and find a bit of lead near one corner. Now the assumption “all outcomes are equally likely” is not true anymore. You’d need some pretty clever maths and precise measurements, or extensive experiments, to find the probability. There is nothing less “objective“, just the fact that this probability is harder to find.


Are probabilities in games of chance any more objective than in other contexts?

Yes, in most cases. What distinguishes games of chance from other contexts is that the description of probabilities is well defined: A coin has two states HT of equal probability.
But what about predicting the survival probabilities for certain forms of cancer?
Here, a complete probabilistic picture is not as straightforward and requires some subjective  measures (affect of lifestyle, diet, exercise, financial status)

You ask:

Are probabilities in games of chance any more objective than in other contexts?

You go on to say:

we often talk about probabilities in contexts of events that are unrelated to games of chance, or even events that don’t seem repeatable. For example, you could ask the question: “How probable is it that John is the murderer of this body?”

So, the short answer to your question is that there are different theories or interpretations of probability (SEP) that are used in different contexts. That is, when dealing with a flip of a coin, frequentism seems to be the best theory of probability, but under some other circumstance we might apply Bayesian thinking. For instance, if John seems like a nice guy, and then we find out that John is a convicted serial killer who has escaped, we certainly aren't going to think about answering the question based on coin flips and dice rolls, or other forms of empirical probability because human psychology does not fit that context.
Now the question more specifically asks after whether or not probabilities in some contexts are more objective than ones in others, and the answer to that is a resounding yes. Evidential probability (SEP) is almost the definition of objective probability because the empirical methods to determine the probability are certainly objective, at least in the intersubjective sense that science handles objectivity. Compare that to subjective measures of degrees of belief (SEP) where people (on a reading of logic that might be termed "irrationalism") are considered fundamentally biased in the sense of Kahneman's Thinking, Fast and Slow.
